# Unable to get getStatusCode of locationSettings unless mSettingsClient.checkLocationSettings is executed

Tags: android, gps, location, google-location-services

Is there any way to know if LocationSettingsStatusCodes is equal to RESOLUTION_REQUIRED without having to call mSettingsClient.checkLocationSettings all the time? May be from location object of onLocationChanged listener?

```
 mSettingsClient.checkLocationSettings(mLocationSettingsRequest).addOnSuccessListener(mActivity,
                new OnSuccessListener<LocationSettingsResponse>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(LocationSettingsResponse locationSettingsResponse) {
                        Log.i(this.getClass().getName(), "Location settings ok");
                        mFusedProviderClient.requestLocationUpdates(mLocationRequest, mLocationCallback, Looper.myLooper()).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                                
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }).addOnFailureListener(mActivity, new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        int statusCode = ((ApiException) e).getStatusCode();
                        if(statusCode == LocationSettingsStatusCodes.RESOLUTION_REQUIRED){
                            //Location settings not satisfied.
                                try {
                                    // Cast to a resolvable exception.
                                    ResolvableApiException resolvable = (ResolvableApiException) e;
                                    resolvable.startResolutionForResult(
                                            mActivity,
                                            AppCommand.REQUEST_GOOGLE_ACCURACY);
                                } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException ex) {
                                    Log.e(this.getClass().getName(), "SendIntentException " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
                                }
                            }
        
    
                        Log.e(this.getClass().getName(), "Check location permission failed: " +e.getLocalizedMessage());
                    }
                }
            );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> if LocationSettingsStatusCodes is equal to RESOLUTION_REQUIRED

This is not true.
`LocationSettingsStatusCodes` is **not** equal to `RESOLUTION_REQUIRED`.
`LocationSettingsStatusCodes` is an encapsulation of the failure exception handling mechanism, but other exceptions may occur in the actual process,and We cannot guarantee what other conditions may cause the permission check to fail.

Answer (score 0):

You don’t have to check the location settings all the time when you try to get the location.  The two calls of `mSettingsClient.checkLocationSettings`, and `mFusedProviderClient.requestLocationUpdates` could be called separately.  Since they are asynchronous callbacks, make sure the checkLocationSettings call first, and after it finished then call the requestLocationUpdate.

One suggestion is call the checkLocationSettings in the `onCreate()`, and `onResume()` of the fragment or activity.  And call the `requestLocationUpdates()` when needed.